# How to populate an rdl table based on data returned from a query?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, rdl

I have absolutely no experience working with rdl files and I received a ticket from a client asking us to display multiple reports in one report. What I have done so far is created a master rdl file that contains a sub-report. That subreport is linked to another rdl file which is the actual report that is normally generated. What I want to do is generate a list of those subreports based on the data received in an array from a query. So if there are 6 elements in the array then I need to have 6 subreports generated, with each report using data from the appropriate index in the array.

I managed to figure out how to connect the data for one subreport but I have no idea how to scale that programatically.

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand...  Could you add some images that show what you are trying to achieve?  Do you know the locations and names of the required subreports or are you trying to pull them from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

The basic steps are

- Create a subreport that accepts parameters (done I guess)
- Create a master report (done)
- Create a dataset in your master report that contains a row of data for each subreport. For example. If you subreport showed employee details for a single employee, your main report might contain a dataset that lists employee IDs for a department.
- Add a tablix  to your main report, remove header row and leave only a single column. Stretch this column to fit your report width
- Set the datasetname property of the tablix to the name of your dataset, (now it will produce one row per employee)
- Right click the tablix cell and insert subreport
- Right click the subreport placeholder -> properties then choose your subreport form the drop down.
- Set the subreport parameter(s) to be the values from your dataset (e.g. EmployeeID = empID)

That's it.

You main report will run, the tablix will create a row per record in your dataset, this in turn will give you a subreport per row in your dataset, each of those subreports will have the value of the field from that row passed to it.

If you need more help, I'll try to track down a similar answer I posted a while back which had more detail.